# linear-gradient doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

linear gradient doesn't work in Firefox and IE here is my code:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient( top, #f1f5f0, #739a65) ;

    background:-moz-linear-gradient( top, #f1f5f, #739a65);
    background:-o-linear-gradient( top, #f1f5f0,#739a65);
    background:linear-gradient(to top, #f1f5f0,#739a65);
}
```

Update: I resolved it by using backgound-image:linear-gradient...

Comment: I just tested it, and it works in the latest versions for Chrome/FF and IE

Comment: in chrome works, but in edge and mozilla doesn't

Comment: What version of FF? I'm on 42.0.

Comment: I'm on FF 3(don't know more specs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have FF3, and you haven't stated the IE version but linear gradients are/were only supported from FF3.6 and IE from IE10.

If possible, I'd suggest you upgrade to the latest version of both. FF3 is *very* old.

[**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)